# Ruby error - undefined method `test_path' for #<#<Class:0x4022a00>:0x4028ee0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this error:

```
undefined method `test_path' for #<#<Class:0x4022a00>:0x4028ee0>
```

I made this link:

```
<%= link_to "Alex Link", test_path(@test) %>
```

and I made this controller: test_controller.rb

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def test
  end
end
```

And I added this to routes.rb

```
root :to => 'test_path#hello'
```

Where did I go wrong?

I am just trying to learn how to route ruby controllers by hand.

Comment: "test_path" is a method *returning* the path, not the path itself. That method will not be created if you do not create a route for it via something like "match" or "resource" as described in your earlier question, which this is really a part of.

Comment: @DaveNewton Dave your explanations are difficult to understand. "test_path" is mentioned 2 times in the snippets I posted. To which of those two times are you referring to?

Comment: try by putting `resource :test` in routes.rb instead of what you have it.

Comment: You only use it as a method once. Also, what is the "@test" variable supposed to be?

Comment: @uDaY thanks that worked to make the html page render. But when I click the link now, I get this error: "uninitialized constant TestsController"   ....how does it want me to initialize it?

Comment: You seriously need to go through a tutorial--you're doing this the hard way. You don't have a "TestsController", you have a "TestController". Because you're not following rails conventions. Because you're not following a tutorial. (I'm assuming you've at least put it in the right directory, obviously, and there aren't typos.)

Comment: may be because you might not have something like `Test` model. Also I agree with DaveNewton. You are not doing it in correct rails conventions

Comment: @uDaY I named my controller test_controller.rb but I did not add a model yet. Right now there is no db connected to this app.

Comment: @GeekedOut, you are getting that error coz you dont have any model which says `Test`. Also the controller is usually pluralized. like TestsController. for model to be `Test`. Hope it helps

Comment: @uDaY No, he's not. The model layer has nothing to do with any of these errors.

Comment: @uDaY I renamed my controller to "tests_controller.rb" and that worked to some degree. The error changed to be: "Expected C:/Sites/blog/app/controllers/tests_controller.rb to define TestsController" what does that mean? It can't find the newly renamed conroller?

Comment: Now I get an error: "The action 'show' could not be found for TestsController" -- should I add that to the routes.rb ? Or also update the controller somehow? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, he was getting the "uninitialized constant for his TestController. isnt supposed to be because of unassociated model although the routes have been declared? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @GeekedOut, no you get the 7 CRUD routes with declaring the routes as `resources` in routes so I think its coz you might not be having show action in your controller.

Comment: I added this to my controller:   def show

   respond_to do |test|
        
    end
  end

Comment: but that didn't fix much.  What should be instead of |test| ? Can I just output some dummy variable and display it to the screen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st part: put `resources :test` instead of what you have in routes.rb file

2nd Answer: Because you dont have a model associated with your controller you are getting that error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No. I said it before I'll say it again: this has nothing to do with the presence of a model, you do not ever *need* a model associated with a controller or any routing.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I know that you can go away with just the Controller & View in Rails. but I was referring about the error.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the lack of a model either.